# rails-backbone gem error for model with two-word names: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'bind' of undefined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, rubygems, coffeescript

I'm following this example https://github.com/codebrew/backbone-rails#example-usage for the backbone-rails gem. It works fine for models that have one word names but I get the `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'bind' of undefined` error if I try to follow the same pattern for a model with two names.  Here's what I did:

```
rails new blog
```

I added the `rails-backbone` gem into the Gemfile then

```
bundle install

rails g backbone:install

rails g scaffold FriendRequest sender_gender:string recipient_gender:string

rake db:migrate

rails g backbone:scaffold FriendRequest sender_gender:string recipient_gender:string
```

my `app/views/friend_requests/index.html.erb` file looks like this:

```
<h1>Listing friend_requests</h1>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Sender gender</th>
    <th>Recipient gender</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>

<% @friend_requests.each do |friend_request| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= friend_request.sender_gender %></td>
    <td><%= friend_request.recipient_gender %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', friend_request %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_friend_request_path(friend_request) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', friend_request, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>

<br />

<%= link_to 'New Friend request', new_friend_request_path %>


<div id="friend_requests"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    // Blog is the app name
    window.router = new Blog.Routers.FriendRequestRouter({friend_requests: <%= @friend_requests.to_json.html_safe -%>});
    Backbone.history.start();
  });
</script>
```

When I hit `http://localhost:3000/friend_requests` I receive this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'bind' of undefined
```

I copied the code from the console which shows the error inside. I'm not sure the correct protocol for StackOverflow with an error like that but you can see it, it is surrounded by *'s.  If someone wants to edit this question to be displayed properly, that would be appreciated.

```
(function() {
  var _base,
    __bind = function(fn, me){ return function(){ return fn.apply(me, arguments); }; },
    __hasProp = {}.hasOwnProperty,
    __extends = function(child, parent) { for (var key in parent) { if (__hasProp.call(parent, key)) child[key] = parent[key]; } function ctor() { this.constructor = child; } ctor.prototype = parent.prototype; child.prototype = new ctor(); child.__super__ = parent.prototype; return child; };

  (_base = Blog.Views).FriendRequests || (_base.FriendRequests = {});

  Blog.Views.FriendRequests.IndexView = (function(_super) {

    __extends(IndexView, _super);

    function IndexView() {
      this.render = __bind(this.render, this);

      this.addOne = __bind(this.addOne, this);

      this.addAll = __bind(this.addAll, this);
      return IndexView.__super__.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
    }

    IndexView.prototype.template = JST["backbone/templates/friend_requests/index"];

    IndexView.prototype.initialize = function() {
      return this.options.friendRequests.bind('reset', this.addAll);
***Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'bind' of undefined***
    };

    IndexView.prototype.addAll = function() {
      return this.options.friendRequests.each(this.addOne);
    };

    IndexView.prototype.addOne = function(friendRequest) {
      var view;
      view = new Blog.Views.FriendRequests.FriendRequestView({
        model: friendRequest
      });
      return this.$("tbody").append(view.render().el);
    };

    IndexView.prototype.render = function() {
      $(this.el).html(this.template({
        friendRequests: this.options.friendRequests.toJSON()
      }));
      this.addAll();
      return this;
    };

    return IndexView;

  })(Backbone.View);

}).call(this);
```

And finally, the coffeescript file `index_view.js.coffee` which generates the above error is

```
Blog.Views.FriendRequests ||= {}

class Blog.Views.FriendRequests.IndexView extends Backbone.View
  template: JST["backbone/templates/friend_requests/index"]

  initialize: () ->
    @options.friendRequests.bind('reset', @addAll)

  addAll: () =>
    @options.friendRequests.each(@addOne)

  addOne: (friendRequest) =>
    view = new Blog.Views.FriendRequests.FriendRequestView({model : friendRequest})
    @$("tbody").append(view.render().el)

  render: =>
    $(@el).html(@template(friendRequests: @options.friendRequests.toJSON() ))
    @addAll()

    return this
```

I'm assuming it is just something simple like not using the proper capitalization or other convention for models with two names but I can't seem to figure it out.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT-----

I just thought of this, but I would pay closest attention to my `app/views/friend_requests/index.html.erb` file as it is the one place that I actually hand-edited my code.  Everything else is auto-generated by the `rails-backbone` gem.

--------EDIT #2--------------

As per the first comment asking where the IndexView was instantiated it is here in `/app/assets/javascripts/backbone/routers/friend_requests_router.js.coffee`:

```
class Blog.Routers.FriendRequestsRouter extends Backbone.Router
  initialize: (options) ->
    @friendRequests = new Blog.Collections.FriendRequestsCollection()
    @friendRequests.reset options.friendRequests

  routes:
    "new"      : "newFriendRequest"
    "index"    : "index"
    ":id/edit" : "edit"
    ":id"      : "show"
    ".*"        : "index"

  newFriendRequest: ->
    @view = new Blog.Views.FriendRequests.NewView(collection: @friend_requests)
    $("#friend_requests").html(@view.render().el)

  index: ->
    @view = new Blog.Views.FriendRequests.IndexView(friend_requests: @friend_requests)
    $("#friend_requests").html(@view.render().el)

  show: (id) ->
    friend_request = @friend_requests.get(id)

    @view = new Blog.Views.FriendRequests.ShowView(model: friend_request)
    $("#friend_requests").html(@view.render().el)

  edit: (id) ->
    friend_request = @friend_requests.get(id)

    @view = new Blog.Views.FriendRequests.EditView(model: friend_request)
    $("#friend_requests").html(@view.render().el)
```

Comment: Where do you instantiate your `Blog.Views.FriendRequests.IndexView`?

Comment: See the Edit #2: I believe it is in friend_requests_router.js.coffee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your router does this:

```
index: ->
  @view = new Blog.Views.FriendRequests.IndexView(friend_requests: @friend_requests)
  #...
```

Note the `friend_requests:` part. Your `Blog.Views.FriendRequests.IndexView`, however, is always looking for `@options.friendRequests`:

```
initialize: () ->
  @options.friendRequests.bind('reset', @addAll)
```

Backbone will take care of [`@options`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-constructor):

> When creating a new View, the options you pass are attached to the view as `this.options`, for future reference.

but it won't convert underscored names to camel-cased names. Your view should be looking at `@options.friend_requests` rather than `@options.friendRequests` (or use `friendRequests:` when instantiating your view). You might want to to stick to just one naming convention (lower and underscores or camel-case) for variables. Underscores are more common in Ruby and Rails so that might be a good choice (OTOH, camel-case is pretty common in JavaScript so...).

PS: Backbone views already have a jQuery'd version of `@el` in [`@$el`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-%24el) so you don't have to `$(@el)` anywhere, just use `@$el`.

---

**Backbone 1.1.0 Update**: As of 1.1.0, Backbone views no longer set `this.options` to the view's options automatically, if you want that behavior then you'll have to do it yourself:

```
initialize: (options) ->
  @options = options
  #...
```

or:

```
initialize: (@options) ->
  #...
```

You can also grab the options out of `options` that you need and throw away the rest:

```
initialize: (options) ->
  @friend_requests = options.friendRequests
  #...
```

I prefer the latter approach as it makes your view's options very explicit and easy to track.

Comment: hah, yea i was showing this to somebody and commented how in a single file there was friend_requests, friendRequests and FriendRequests.  :)  I'll fix this up and deliver the checkmark.  Thanks!

Comment: The hardest errors to see are the ones that are staring you in the face.